# Is Matthew 6:3 a hebrew idiom?

Tags: matthew, idiom

Matthew 6:3 NASB

> But when you [b]give to the poor, do not let your left hand know what your right hand is doing,

It seems impracticable that one hand would not know what the other hand is doing, so was Christ using figurative or idiomatic phrase here

Is this a Hebrew idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the comments from some who are better informed about Matt 6:3 -

Ellicott:

> (3) **Let not thy left hand know**.—The phrase was probably
> proverbial, and indicates, in the form of free hyperbole, extremest
> secrecy. It is possible that there may be some reference to the
> practice of using the right hand in offering gifts at the altar. The
> symbolical application, though an afterthought, is yet suggestive. The
> “right hand” is the higher spiritual element in us that leads to acts
> of true charity, the “left” is the baser, self-seeking nature. We
> ought, as it were, to set a barrier between the two, as far as
> possible, i.e., to exclude that mingling of motives, which is at least
> the beginning of evil.

Barnes:

> **Let not thy left hand know** ... - This is a proverbial expression, signifying that the action should be done as secretly as possible. The
> Hebrews often attribute actions to members which properly belong to
> persons. The encouragement for performing our acts of charity in
> secret is that it will be pleasing to God; that he will see the act,
> however secret it may be, and will openly reward it. If the reward is
> not granted in this life, it will be in the life to come. In
> multitudes of cases, however, alms given to the poor are "lent to the
> Lord" Proverbs 19:17, and will be repaid in this life. Rarely, perhaps
> never, has it been found that the man who is liberal to the poor has
> ever suffered by it in his worldly circumstances.

However, the origin of the proverb is not stated - it could just as easily been a Greek proverb about secrecy employed by Jesus.

Comment: +1 good answer.